# Finding Array index using VB6.0

Tags: arrays, vb6

I m trying to find out array index using visual basic. I tried some code with VB.Net and getting correct output. Below is the code I am using,

```
Dim FindThisString as String="EFGH"
Dim MyArray() As String={"ABCD","EFGH","IJKLM"}
For Each Str As String In MyArray
If Str.Contains(FindThisString) Then
    MsgBox(Str.IndexOf(FindThisString))
End If 
Next
```

Now I want to try the same method with VB 6.0. I am using Instr function but it is giving me string index in entire string and I am looking for array index i.e. index of string "EFGH" in MyArray.

Here is the VB6 code I'm trying:

```
Dim MyString as String 
Dim str as Variant 
MyString="ABCD/EFGH/IJKLM" 
Dim MyArray() as String 
MyArray = split(MyString,"/") 
Dim inIndex as Integer 
For Each Str In MyArray 
   inIndex= Instr(str,"EFGH") 
   MsgBox inIndex 
Next
```

Comment: Show us your VB6 code also. You'll have to iterate over the array in VB6 too.

Comment: Dim MyString as String
   Dim str as Variant
   MyString="ABCD/EFGH/IJKLM"
   Dim MyArray() as String
   MyArray = split(MyString,"/")
   Dim inIndex as Integer
   For Each Str In MyArray
 inIndex= Instr(str,"EFGH")
    MsgBox inIndex
  Next

Comment: @idstam : I a trying above VB6 code

Answer (score 1):

You would basically use the same algorithm:

- Loop through the array (you'll need to use a `Variant` as the loop variable for VB Classic `For Each`),
- verify if the array entry contains the substring in question (you need to use `InStr` here, since VB Classic does not have `String.Contains`),
- return the index (which you already determined with `InStr`).

The implementation is left as an exercise.

Comment: Hi Heinzi.. I have gone thru your suggestion. But your solution is mostly for string and not for array of string. As Instr in vb6 accept two parameters i.e. Instr(Stringinto, "Stringtosearch"). But i am looking for array index.

Comment: @Mahesh: Ah, but your VB.NET example code does not return the array index: It returns the string index!

Comment: That What I meant to say here. Here is the VB6 code I m trying.. Dim MyString as String Dim str as Variant MyString="ABCD/EFGH/IJKLM" Dim MyArray() as String MyArray = split(MyString,"/") Dim inIndex as Integer For Each Str In MyArray inIndex= Instr(str,"EFGH") MsgBox inIndex Next

Comment: @Mahesh: In that case, use a regular `For` loop instead of a `For Each` loop and return the loop counter.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. will try the same and will let you know.

Answer (score 0):

```
Function IndexOf(ByRef arr() As String, ByVal str As String) As Integer
    Dim joinedStr As String
    Dim strIndex As Integer
    joinedStr = "|" & Join(arr, "|")
    strIndex = InStr(1, joinedStr, str)
    If strIndex = 0 Then
        IndexOf = -1
        Exit Function
    End If
    joinedStr = Mid(joinedStr, 1, strIndex - 1)
    IndexOf = UBound(Split(joinedStr, "|")) - 1
End Function
```